# Form too Large Exception

Tags: java, jetty

When I send a large file using a post request the system shows an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too large1105723>200000
at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:1404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getParameter(Request.java:749)......
```

When I search help for this in Google they give some help e.g.,
         `webappcontext.setMaxFormContentSize(5000000);`

I am using this code but the problem is not solved

Also I am using the code
    `jettyServer.setAttribute("org.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize", 5000000);`

But no result

Note:-I am using Jetty-6.1.0

Answer (score 34):

Try setting System properties via `jetty.xml`

```
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
      <Arg>org.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
      <Arg>500000</Arg>
    </Call>
```

ok you can configure it from your web app

Add WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml file in your web application
          and configure the parameter in that file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
  "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

  <Configure id="WebAppContext" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <Set name="maxFormContentSize" type="int">600000</Set>
  </Configure>
```

[**Document**](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/jetty-web.xml)

### Version 7 or Higher

Since version 7, Jetty's classes have moved to a different package. You must replace `org.mortbay...` with `org.eclipse...` (Thanks to David for his comment).

Comment: Thanks For Writing Code But Their Is One Big Problem i.e We Doesn't Maintains The Server please Tell me Their is Another way To Do This

Comment: @Narendra nnvd you deploy your app using maven plugin ?

Comment: I am Using The Server It Has Been Already Setuped  We Doesn't Change the Xml File.

Comment: Is Their Anyway To Do This Other Xml Files ? We Cann't Edit Jetty Xml Files Please Understand My Problem

Comment: @Narendra nnvd No its just you need to add a config file in your web app , you won't touch the actual jetty's config file

Comment: Do i need to create jetty-web.xml file or need add it in web.xml file and will work without doing any extract modifications?

Comment: @Narendra nnvd you need to add a new file check the documentation given

Comment: creating document with file name jetty-web.xml by using above code what ever you show and it places in Webapp/WEB-INF/  folder in  my project. when i restart the my project.Still I got a exception

Comment: @Narendra nnvd it should work recheck it also check this doc http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty-web.xml

Comment: my problem is solved my setting of  "webappcontext.getServletContext().getContextHandler()
    .setMaxFormContentSize(10000000);"

Comment: @Narendra nnvd Thanks for sharing :) it took too long time but its good you have updated here :)

Comment: In maven jetty plugin:
<webAppConfig>
  <maxFormContentSize>500000</maxFormContentSize>
</webAppConfig>

Answer (score 11):

```
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
//... other code here...//
int port = 8080;
Server server = new Server(port);
server.setAttribute("org.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize", -1);
```

This code works on jetty 6.0.2 which I'm using.
The size of "-1" means the form has no limit I tryed to post a form large 20,000,000 bytes and I had no problem.
For eclipse releases of Jetty(jetty 7) you have to use the following code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
//... other code here...//
int port = 8080;
Server server = new Server(port);
server.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", -1);
```

Comment: Is that right ? On my environment, to configure "-1" let jetty server 
 to limit uploaded file size. Perhaps, it's up to the version of jetty application server.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I'm not able to make any changes to jetty.xml, so instead I simply set some options to adjust the maxFormContentSize like so:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=5000000"
```

This exists in the shell script that we use to launch our instance of Solr.

Comment: This method worked for me but `System.setProperty` oddly didn't.

Answer (score 4):

More documentation on form size: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Form_Size

Answer (score 3):

I came across this problem too (running Jetty embedded in another application, so I'm not using jetty.xml).

I used the `setMaxFormContentSize` method on the `ContextHandler` class, which fixed the "form too large" exception. (See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Setting_a_ServletContext for an example of creating/using a context handler).

Answer (score 3):

```
            <!-- Development Jetty -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/${project.build.finalName}</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</name>
                        <value>10485760</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Work for jetty 8 in maven plugin

Answer (score 2):

```
webappcontext.getServletContext().getContextHandler() .setMaxFormContentSize(10000000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I use jetty 9.2.3.v20140905, and i fixed the problem use the follow:

- confiure pom.xml

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
  <configuration>
    <jettyXml>
      src/main/resources/jetty/jetty.xml
    </jettyXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

- configure jetty.xml

```html
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
    <Arg>-1</Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how old your Jetty Version is you are using (in my case jetty-5.1.14 embedded in Eclipse Equinox),  it also could be that the property needs to be ***org.mortbay.http.HttpRequest.maxFormContentSize***

From: org.mortbay.http.HttpRequest

```
/**
 * Max size of the form content. Limits the size of the data a client can push at the server.
 * Set via the org.mortbay.http.HttpRequest.maxContentSize system property.
 */
public static int __maxFormContentSize = Integer.getInteger(
        "org.mortbay.http.HttpRequest.maxFormContentSize", 200000).intValue();
```

So you need to do something like this in your application on startup to set the value:

```
System.setProperty("org.mortbay.http.HttpRequest.maxFormContentSize", "10000000");
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above Solution worked for me ,

So in order to make this work I set the system property before creating the server, rather then setting it as server attribute

```
 System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", "500000000");

 Server server = ServerFactory.createServer(host, port, contextPath, war);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue on ActiveMQ so i had to edit the jetty.xml and add

```
  <property name="maxFormContentSize" value="-1" />
```

to the handler property.

from:-

```
 <property name="handler">
 <bean id="sec" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
 <property name="handlers">
 <list>
 <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <property name="contextPath" value="/admin" /> 
  <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" /> 
  <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" /> 
  </bean>
```

to

```
 <property name="handler">
 <bean id="sec" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
 <property name="handlers">
 <list>
 <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <property name="contextPath" value="/admin" /> 
  <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" /> 
  <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" /> 
  <property name="maxFormContentSize" value="-1" /> 
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jetty in embedded mode,try this.

```
    ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletHandler.setMaxFormContentSize(1024*1024*1024);//size you want to allow.
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Spring boot and set `server.jetty.max-http-post-size: maxSize` in application.properties to fix it.

```
server.jetty.max-http-post-size: 500000
```

Answer (score 1):

set in `jetty/webapps` -> configure `.xml` (e.g `jetty-web.xml`) file

`"-1"` for unlimited content

`<Set name="maxFormContentSize" type="int">600000</Set>`

OR

`<Set name="maxFormContentSize" type="int">-1</Set>`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because of changes in Jetty since version 7, but I only had success like so:

in jetty-web.xml, add the below to the Server object (1000000 is an example size, obv)

```
<Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
      <Arg>1000000</Arg>
</Call>
```

full file might look something like mine

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
      <Arg>1000000</Arg>
    </Call>

    <Ref id="DeploymentManager">
          <Call id="webappprovider" name="addAppProvider">
            <Arg>
(...)
```

ref http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Form_Size

Answer (score 0):

If you're running from eclipse/spring add the below to vm arguments
-Dorg.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize=-1

Answer (score 0):

Start jenkins by adding command line argument
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=500000

i.e java  -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=500000 -jar jenkins.war

Answer (score 0):

#### ActiveMQ:

The problem here is with Jetty, on which ActiveMQ is based. You can find more details here, [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Form_Size)

**Solution is** in `apache-activemq-5.9.0/bin/win64/wrapper.conf` file, add the following line **a** after **b** (refer below).

- **a**: `wrapper.java.additional.16=-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=1000000`
- **b**: `wrapper.java.additional.15=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/login.config`

If you are running on a 32 bit computer, then please add the same line in `apache-activemq-5.9.0/bin/win32/wrapper.conf`.

Happy Coding..