# Handling form too large Exception without applying the org.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize param

Tags: jetty, limit, http-post

As per the solutions mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861455/form-too-large-exception) , we need to set the `maxFormContentSize` parameter. But such a solution can lead to [DoS through hash table vulnerability](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2011/Dec/477) .

Is there any way other than limiting the post request, may be by breaking it into multiple requests ? I need to use this on a web client with no `javascript` support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/085c79d7d6cfbccc02821ffdb64968593df3e0bf

Jetty added a mechanism to handle this concern quite some time ago by calling setMaxFormKeys on the ContextHandler.  Above is the commit adding that support in and the corresponding test case.  Exists in jetty 7.6.x and 8.1.x as well as in jetty 9 milestone releases.