# Jetty - Form too large Error

Tags: solr, jetty

I have been working on Solr and running some load tests on it. After some point, I keep getting

```
Nov 29, 2012 3:34:43 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: null:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too large275768>200000
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterMap(Request.java:705)
at org.apache.solr.request.ServletSolrParams.<init>(ServletSolrParams.java:29)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.StandardRequestParser.parseParamsAndFillStreams(SolrRequestParsers.java:394)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parse(SolrRequestParsers.java:115)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Basically I made searches on google and stackoverflow too, and all I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861455/form-too-large-exception) and applying the solutions there didnt helped at all..

I have tried to modify that value from `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.JettySolrRunner`too but even changing value from that file didnt helped at all.

anyone knows how to change max allowed form size for an embedded Jetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the source code of Solr, I found one place where I can set the form size. The class I have modified is `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.JettySolrRunner.java` , basically adding some large number for the form size...

although it works, I am still confused why I cant set this value via config files