# How to change Jetty settings through SparkJava? / Form too Large Exception / org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, spark-java

I'm using SparkJava 2.2 which is using Jetty 9.0.2.

I'm getting "Form too large" exception which is thrown by Jetty. I already know how to solve this problem if I was using Jetty directly:

[Form too Large Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861455/form-too-large-exception)

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-form-size.html

PROBLEM :

Now I need to find a way to change `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize` setting through SparkJava. Is there a way to do this?

I must note that other methods (JVM_OPTS, System.setProperty) do not work for me for some reason. I'm still getting the same exception.

Stacktrace:

```
[qtp1858644635-27] ERROR spark.webserver.MatcherFilter -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too large 308913>200000
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterMap(Request.java:765)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameterMap(ServletRequestWrapper.java:193)
    at spark.QueryParamsMap.<init>(QueryParamsMap.java:59)
    at spark.Request.initQueryMap(Request.java:364)
    at spark.Request.queryMap(Request.java:349)
    at spark.webserver.RequestWrapper.queryMap(RequestWrapper.java:213)
    at com.xyz.analytics.webservice.RequestTools.getRequestQueryMap(RequestTools.java:27)
    at com.xyz.analytics.webservice.RequestTools.getMandrillQueryParams(RequestTools.java:22)
    at com.xyz.analytics.webservice.Endpoints.lambda$initiateEndpointsAndExceptionHandlers$2(Endpoints.java:61)
    at com.xyz.analytics.webservice.Endpoints$$Lambda$3/1485697819.handle(Unknown Source)
    at spark.SparkBase$1.handle(SparkBase.java:311)
    at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:159)
    at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

## Edit:

> I must note that other methods (JVM_OPTS, System.setProperty) do not work for me.

Well, debugger doesn't even stop at any breakpoint set within `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handlerContextHandler`... Plus when it stops at `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` breakpoints, _context property is null. Seems that SparkJava is handling it differently. Dead end.

Request does one more thing before setting `maxFormContentSize = 200000;`. It checks _channel.getServer().getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize"). 
Except Server's attribute collection is empty... And I don't see any way to add any attribute. Jetty Server is created by SparkBase.init() which calls SparkServer.ignite(). 
But it doesn't help us much. It's not easy to "break in" to make our own adjustments. It seems pretty hopeless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news everyone :) 
In Spark 2.6 (released April 2017) embedded Jetty is fully configurable!
Release notes: http://sparkjava.com/news#spark-26-released

See the original future request for more details here: https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/314
and related pull request here:
https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/813

NOTE that it is also possible to run Spark on another web server instead of the embedded Jetty server:
http://sparkjava.com/documentation#other-web-server

Answer (score 4):

Not possible with Spark 2.2

The [creation of the ServerConnector is hardcoded in the SparkServer](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/2.2/src/main/java/spark/webserver/SparkServer.java#L162-L202), you cannot change those values after the fact, they have to be passed into the ServerConnector before server start.

Would recommend filing a bug with Spark to make that configurable.

https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues

Comment: BTW, there is one trick. I could create Jetty server myself... By creating my own SparkServerFactory... Although it's not the best solution really. And for what? To be able to change one config param? Sounds silly ;)

Comment: Yeah, as I was researching spark for the answer, I wound up filing a bunch of new bugs with spark as well.

Comment: It seems nothing will ever change in this matter. So I accept the answer that it's impossible. Thx Joakim.

Link to the issue I've created: https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/314

Answer (score 0):

Well, having access to the **server object**, you can always do something like:

```
server.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", 1024 * 1024);
```

Hope this helps!